# How to add button to TableView using FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I found many example how to add button to TableView but none shows how to use `fxml` . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282230/fxml-javafx-8-tableview-make-a-delete-button-in-each-row-and-delete-the-row-a) is one of the test codes I'm trying to convert to `fxml`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GestureEvents extends Application {
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Label label = new Label("Friends");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        final Label actionTaken = new Label();

        TableColumn<Person, Person> unfriendCol = new TableColumn<>("Anti-social");
        unfriendCol.setMinWidth(40);
        unfriendCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue()));
        unfriendCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
            private final Button deleteButton = new Button("Unfriend");

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);

                if (person == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    return;
                }

                setGraphic(deleteButton);
                deleteButton.setOnAction(event -> data.remove(person));
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(unfriendCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        table.setPrefHeight(250);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, actionTaken);
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried creating `fxml` . But I don't know how to specify the "button" field in the `fxml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.PersonTableController">
   <center>
      <SplitPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <items>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Main Table" />
                  <TextField fx:id="filterField" />
                  <TableView fx:id="personTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" onEditStart="#initialize" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" onEditStart="#initialize" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: You can't do this directly with FXML, because it requires a cell factory. Just set the cell factory in the controller.

Comment: Thank you. But if I don't mention button column in fxml, then it will not show up in the scene builder

Comment: You still define the column in FXML (i.e. create the column in Scene Builder), you just can't create the cell factory there (so you won't see the buttons in Scene Builder, but that should not be a problem). Create the column in the usual way, and set the cell factory in the controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code for include a button in a FXML file you can use:

```
<Button fx:id="buttonId" text="Ok" onMouseClicked="#onMouseClickedEvent"/>
```

You can find more information here:
[Using FXML to Create a User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm)

Comment: This is a true statement, but what does it have to do with this question?