# Javafx - Add action to button click on table row

Tags: java, sql, javafx, fxml

I have a problem with the below code. On click the last row button, i want to get the current row data and execute a delete to SQL database bun I don't know how to get the row data.

I create the table and column in the fxml file and populate it with data and button on MainController and HomeController but I spent many hours looking for a solution to get the row data on witch the button is located.

HomeController.java

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable{
    ObservableList<Book> recordsBook = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<BorrowedBook> recordsBorrowedBooks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
    public ObservableList<Book> getBooks(){
        DatabaseConnection connectionNew = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectionNew.getConnection();

        String books = "SELECT * FROM books";
        try{
            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(books);

            while(rs.next()){
                Book book = new Book(rs.getInt("Id"),rs.getString("Title"),rs.getString("PublicatedOn"),rs.getString("PublishingHouse"),rs.getString("Cover"),rs.getString("Summary"),rs.getInt("Price"));
                recordsBook.add(book);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
        }

        return recordsBook;
    }

    public ObservableList<BorrowedBook> getBorrowedBooks(int userId){
        DatabaseConnection connectionNew = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectionNew.getConnection();

        String books = "SELECT b.Title,a.borrowDate,a.returnDate,a.id FROM borrowed_books a INNER JOIN books b on a.bookId = b.Id INNER JOIN users c on a.userId = c.Id WHERE a.userId = " + userId;
        try{
            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(books);
            while(rs.next()){
                int remainingDays = getDaysDiff(rs.getString("ReturnDate"));

                Button returnOnClick = new Button("Inapoiaza");
                returnOnClick.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                    System.out.println(event);
                });

                BorrowedBook borrowedBook = new BorrowedBook(rs.getString("Title"), rs.getString("BorrowDate"), rs.getString("ReturnDate"), remainingDays, returnOnClick);

                recordsBorrowedBooks.add(borrowedBook);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
        }

        return recordsBorrowedBooks;
    }

    public boolean borrowBook(Integer bookId, Integer userId) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseConnection connectionNew = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectionNew.getConnection();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        String checkBookExist = "SELECT count(1) FROM borrowed_books WHERE bookId= ? AND userId =? AND `returnDate` > CURRENT_DATE()";
        PreparedStatement prepareStatementSelect=connectDB.prepareStatement(checkBookExist);
        prepareStatementSelect.setInt(1, bookId);
        prepareStatementSelect.setInt(2, userId);

        try{
            ResultSet rs = prepareStatementSelect.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){

                if(rs.getInt(1) == 0){
                    String borrowString = "INSERT INTO borrowed_books (bookId, userId, borrowDate, returnDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
                    PreparedStatement prepareStatementInsert=connectDB.prepareStatement(borrowString);
                    prepareStatementInsert.setInt(1, bookId);
                    prepareStatementInsert.setInt(2, userId);
                    prepareStatementInsert.setString(3, date.toString());
                    prepareStatementInsert.setString(4, String.valueOf(date.plusMonths(1)));
                    try{
                        prepareStatementInsert.executeUpdate();
                        return true;
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
                    }
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int getDaysDiff(String dateStop) throws ParseException {
        LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate dt2 = LocalDate.parse(dateStop);

        long diffDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dt1, dt2);

        return (int)diffDays;
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
package com.example.library;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    private static String paneName;
    private static String defaultImagePath = "C:\\Users\\costi\\Desktop\\LibraryImages\\";
    private static String defaultImageName = "default.png";
    public TableView<Book> tableViewSearch, tableViewHome;
    public TableView<BorrowedBook> tableViewBorrowed;
    public TableColumn<Book,String> colActions, colSearchTitle, colHomeTitle, colSearchPublicatedOn, colHomePublicatedOn, colSearchPublishingHouse, colHomePublishingHouse, colSearchSummary, colHomeSummary, colBorrowedTitle, colBorrowedDateStart, colBorrowedDateEnd;
    public TableColumn<Book,Integer> colSearchPrice, colHomePrice, colSearchId, colHomeId, colBorrowedRemainingDays;
    @FXML
    private Button cancelButton, menuHomeButton, menuSearchButton, borrowBookButton, menuBorrowButton;
    @FXML
    private Pane paneHome, paneSearch, paneBookDetails, paneBorrowed;
    @FXML
    private TextField searchField, titleField, publishingHouseField, priceField, bookIdField;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker publishedOnField;
    @FXML
    private TextArea summaryTextArea;
    @FXML
    private FlowPane flowPaneCoverImage;
    @FXML
    private Label statusLabel;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        paneHome.toFront();
        setPaneName("paneHome");
        setMainData();
    }
    public void setMainData(){
        colHomeId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
        colHomeTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Title"));
        colHomePublicatedOn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PublicatedOn"));
        colHomePublishingHouse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PublishingHouse"));
        colHomeSummary.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Summary"));
        colHomePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        tableViewHome.setRowFactory( tv -> {
            TableRow<Book> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty()) ) {
                    paneBookDetails.toFront();
                    Book rowData = row.getItem();

                    String date = rowData.getPublicatedOn();
                    var dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    var dateTime = LocalDate.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);

                    bookIdField.setText(Integer.toString(rowData.getId()));
                    titleField.setText(rowData.getTitle());
                    publishingHouseField.setText(rowData.getPublishingHouse());
                    priceField.setText(Integer.toString(rowData.getPrice()));
                    publishedOnField.setValue(dateTime);
                    summaryTextArea.setText(rowData.getSummary());

                    InputStream stream = null;
                    try {
                        stream = new FileInputStream(defaultImagePath + rowData.getCover());
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        try {
                            stream = new FileInputStream(defaultImagePath + defaultImageName);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        }
                    }

                    Image image = new Image(stream);
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                    imageView.setFitHeight(flowPaneCoverImage.getHeight());
                    imageView.setFitWidth(flowPaneCoverImage.getWidth());
                    flowPaneCoverImage.getChildren().clear();
                    flowPaneCoverImage.getChildren().add(imageView);
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });

        tableViewHome.setItems(homeController.getBooks());
    }

    public void searchButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        colSearchId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
        colSearchTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Title"));
        colSearchPublicatedOn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PublicatedOn"));
        colSearchPublishingHouse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PublishingHouse"));
        colSearchSummary.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Summary"));
        colSearchPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
        tableViewSearch.setRowFactory( tv -> {
            TableRow<Book> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
                if (ev.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty()) ) {
                    paneBookDetails.toFront();
                    Book rowData = row.getItem();

                    String date = rowData.getPublicatedOn();
                    var dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    var dateTime = LocalDate.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);

                    bookIdField.setText(Integer.toString(rowData.getId()));
                    titleField.setText(rowData.getTitle());
                    publishingHouseField.setText(rowData.getPublishingHouse());
                    priceField.setText(Integer.toString(rowData.getPrice()));
                    publishedOnField.setValue(dateTime);
                    summaryTextArea.setText(rowData.getSummary());

                    InputStream stream = null;
                    try {
                        stream = new FileInputStream(defaultImagePath + rowData.getCover());
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        try {
                            stream = new FileInputStream(defaultImagePath + defaultImageName);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        }
                    }

                    Image image = new Image(stream);
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                    imageView.setFitHeight(flowPaneCoverImage.getHeight());
                    imageView.setFitWidth(flowPaneCoverImage.getWidth());
                    flowPaneCoverImage.getChildren().clear();
                    flowPaneCoverImage.getChildren().add(imageView);
                }
            });
            return row ;
        });
        SearchController searchController = new SearchController();
        tableViewSearch.setItems(searchController.getBooks(searchField.getText()));
    }

    public void setBorrowedData(){
        colBorrowedTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Title"));
        colBorrowedDateStart.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DateStart"));
        colBorrowedDateEnd.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DateEnd"));
        colBorrowedRemainingDays.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("RemainingDays"));
        colActions.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("button"));
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        tableViewBorrowed.setRowFactory( tv -> {
            TableRow<BorrowedBook> row = new TableRow<>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(BorrowedBook item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
                    if (item == null) {
                        setStyle("");
                    } else if (item.getRemainingDays() < 0) {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff5d5d;");
                    } else {
                        setStyle("");
                    }
                }
            };
            return row ;
        });

        tableViewBorrowed.setItems(homeController.getBorrowedBooks(Global.getUserId()));
    }

    public void cancelButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        Stage stage = (Stage) cancelButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public void menuButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        statusLabel.setText("");
        if(event.getSource() == menuHomeButton){
            setPaneName("paneHome");
            paneHome.toFront();
            setMainData();
        }else if(event.getSource() == menuSearchButton){
            setPaneName("paneSearch");
            paneSearch.toFront();
        }else if(event.getSource() == menuBorrowButton){
            setPaneName("paneBorrowed");
            paneBorrowed.toFront();
            setBorrowedData();
        }
    }

    public void backButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        var lastPannelName = getPaneName();
        statusLabel.setText("");
        if(lastPannelName == "paneHome"){
            paneHome.toFront();
        }else if(lastPannelName == "paneSearch"){
            paneSearch.toFront();
        }
    }

    public void borrowBookOnAction(ActionEvent event){
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        int currentUserId = Global.getUserId();
        var currentBookId = Integer.valueOf(bookIdField.getText());
        try {
            boolean inserted = homeController.borrowBook(currentBookId, currentUserId);
            if(inserted){
                statusLabel.setText("Cartea a fost imprumutata pentru 1 luna.");
            }else{
                statusLabel.setText("Ai imprumutat deja aceasta carte.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getPaneName() {
        return paneName;
    }

    public static void setPaneName(String paneName) {
        MainController.paneName = paneName;
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like completely the wrong approach: the button should not be part of your model class (`BorrowedBook`). There are several questions and answers on this site about putting buttons in each row of a table column which do so without polluting your model class.

Comment: That said, I’m not sure I actually see the problem. If you move `returnOnClick.setOnAction(…)` to *after* the line `BorrowedBook borrowedBook = new BorrowedBook(…)` then you can simply do `returnOnClick.serOnAction(event -> { /* do what you need with borrowedBook */ });`

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284751/2189127) of a delete button in each row in a table, without resorting to any of the ridiculous hacks you seem to have in your code.